# How to automatic post submit?

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, submit

I want to post automatically when the input value is written. Please can you help? The form is as follows:

```
<form method="post" action="searchresults.php">
     <input type="text" name="searchresult">
     <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: how would you determine when they're done writing? you could use `onchange` but they would still have to click off the input, so why not click a submit button. if you used `onkeyup` then it would submit after the first button was pressed.

Comment: Depends what you mean by `input value is written`. When the cursor leaves the input field? This will be JS, not PHP.

Comment: Is there some kind of validation it should do first? I think your users would be very frustrated by a form that submits unexpectedly. Most people prefer to hit `Enter`.

Comment: This is a bit broad as is, I'd say start here, https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/. Unless you already have some code that your are having issues with, if so please add that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to work additionally with a simple Timeout. So, it will automatically submit when you are done with writing - with the code above (from patwoj98) you could just write 1 letter until submit. If you want more than 1 letter for your input, then i would do it like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var srt = null;
        $("input[type=text]").on("keyup", function() {
            srt != null && clearTimeout(srt);
            srt = setTimeout(function(){
                $("input[type=submit]").click();
            }, 500);
        });
    });
</script>
<form method="post" action="searchresults.php">
    <input type="text" name="searchresult">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

this would be the way I would realize this.

Comment: Hi Tusk, thank you for the response. I tried the code. After typing in the value, needs to be clicked in vain. This is not suitable for me. It should auto detect.

Answer (score 0):

This should be done with jQuery.

```js
$('#toPost').keyup(function(){
  $('#sub').click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="searchresults.php">

<input type="text" name="searchresult" id="toPost">
<input type="submit" id="sub">
    
</form>
```

Comment: Hi patwoj98, Thank you for the response. Copy and paste works but the barcode reader doesn't work.